# What's the exact geographical dimension range which can be taken offline in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Today, I tried to take my whole country (India) offline, but Google Maps ignored it saying its very large, zoom in. It has also ignored my street saying its too small, zoom out.

I want to know the limits to which `Make Map Offline` is restricted.

Version of Google Maps: 6.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is actually placed on virtual size of the downloaded area. The upper limit is approximately 80MB of data, and the lower limit is smaller than maps displays, somewhere below 100KB, equivalent to around .6 square miles.

[Here](http://www.starkinsider.com/2012/06/google-maps-offline-gps-navigation-hands-on-review.html) is one place that mentions the 80MB limit. In my own testing, I was able to download up to 87MB of data, which is approximately 5625 square miles.

This may have been coincidence, but in my testing, the allowable size ranged from a square .75 miles on a side to a square 75 miles on a side.

Comment: Do you think, my street can consume more storage than my city?

Comment: Also, update your app... Limit of six has been removed.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Let me check for the lower limit. And that's good to know, I'm just going by something I read a while back.

Comment: Found an approximate lower limit.

Comment: Can you please add citation?

Comment: I also came across 80MB thing, but it was few months prior to the question. Your link also cites 3 month old article.

Comment: Also, what about citation for lower limit?

Comment: I arrived at the lower limit by testing it myself on my tablet. I have not found any place that mentions it.